# Create Universal Package during Azure Devops Pipeline using .NET 5

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, .net-5

Been stuck on this for days... need help with my YAML file in a Azure Devops Pipeline. I upgraded to .NET 5 and now my Universal Packages are not being properly built.

Background:

I created a new project in Azure Devops and configured a regular Pipeline and a Release Pipeline. The initial (regular) pipeline does not package the proper Universal package. I tested it by downloaded the files using Azure CL and there are no zip files in it.

Following is my YAML file:

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Builds and publishes a new version of each project in the solution as a nuget package in the Artifacts Feed

name : 5.1$(Rev:.r)

# TRIGGER WHEN WE CHECK IN CODE
trigger:
- master

# RUN THIS PIPELINE IN WINDOWS
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

# USE THESE VARIABLES
variables:
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  universal: 'artifact.web' # the name of the Universal package in the Artifacts feeds

# PERFORM THESE STEPS USING NUGET & MSBUILD: 
# 1. RESTORE from nuget
# 2. BUILD solution
# 3. PACK nuget packages
# 4. PUSH packages to Artifacts feed
# 5. Create the Universal Artifacts 

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '5.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions
    
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1
    checkLatest: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'ae385ab4-48a5-4c76-b207-dfd1050b8ebf/4b05f135-0b1d-48ad-a8e6-d26bf03c2aae' 
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'Build.BuildNumber'
    includesymbols: true 

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'ae385ab4-48a5-4c76-b207-dfd1050b8ebf/4b05f135-0b1d-48ad-a8e6-d26bf03c2aae'
    allowPackageConflicts: true

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'


- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: Universal Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'ae385ab4-48a5-4c76-b207-dfd1050b8ebf/4b05f135-0b1d-48ad-a8e6-d26bf03c2aae'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(universal)' # the name of the Universal package in the Artifacts feeds
    packagePublishDescription: '$(universal)'
```

The pipeline completes successfully but the zip files that represent the Universal package are not created.

When I run the Release Pipeline, I get this error:

```
##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern.<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
```

Any idea how to build a proper Universal file in Azure Devops Pipelines?

Comment: Please show your YAML file before `PublishPipelineArtifact`

Comment: Added my YAML file - thanks @KrzysztofMadej

Comment: Please check whether my answer can help you. If not, please provide a configuration example of the task of getting the package in your release pipeline so that people can better investigate this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with not using the most up to date version of Nuget.

Added this to my YAML

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.8.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and successfully downloaded the package in the release pipeline.

[image]

It may be that the path you took to get the package in release pipeline was wrong, not that the package was not generated.

You can use the [Universal Package task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) to download the package and see if it is successful.

If so, please check the task you download the package. **Universal packages are not stored as zip files**. If you get the package as zip, it will most likely fail. In addition, you can click on the artifact in the build log to see if your path is correct.

[image]

[image]

As shown in the picture:
The path of the `dotnetcore.5.1.2.nupkg` file should be `D:\a\r1\a\Job\dotnetcore.5.1.2.nupkg`.

Comment: That creates a nuget package. I am trying to create a Universal package. Universal packages are stored as zip files on Azure Devops and they can be used in Azure's Web Deploy pipeline. Been doing it like so for a year and it works well because it allows me to revert to past versions quickly.

Comment: @MattEdwardsCdn Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have re-read your question, may I ask whether you have missed .Net publish task? Typically, this task generates the zip file.

Comment: The PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task in my yaml file is what I was using before to create the artifact.